# Is it possible to use Object.create with private class methods?

Tags: javascript

It is possible to use `Object.create` to create a normal Class like this:

```js
class Normal {
  constructor(value) { this.value = value }
  valueOf() { return this.value }
}

const n = Object.create(Normal.prototype, { value: { value: 123 } })
n.valueOf() // 123
```

Can the same be done with private fields?

```js
class Normal {
  #value
  constructor(value) { this.#value = value }
  valueOf() { return this.#value }
}

const n = Object.create(Normal.prototype, { value: { value: 123 } })
n.valueOf() // Error("attempted to get private field on non-instance")
```

Comment: I think the point of `private` encapsulation is to block you from accessing it from outside of the instance, so the answer may be no.

Comment: Well, private class fields is still in Stage 3, so it could change, but as @Mojo says, that would defeat the point of private. See [what the proposal has to say about private access](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#no-backdoor-to-access-private)

Comment: I think the link @HereticMonkey showed is correct `No backdoor to access private`. I was hoping this didn't apply to the creation of the object, but looks like it does.